# Atrapar excepcion divide by zero

Tags: c++

Necesito atrapar la excepcion divide by zero en C++. Estuve leyendo que las excepciones como esta no están definidas en C++; vi algunos ejemplos pero usan `signal()`, en otros usan el `throw()` y la verdad es que me confundió bastante.

Comment: debes usar throw(), aunque si lo puedes evitar haciendo una comprobacion anterior seria lo mas correcto ya que el throw() involucra un gasto de recursos innecesario si se puede evitar

Comment: En este [enlace](https://helloacm.com/how-to-capture-the-integer-divide-by-zero-error-in-c/) tienes varias forms de hacerlo.

Answer (score 2):

> Necesito atrapar la excepcion divide by zero en C++.

Malas noticias, esa excepción no existe. Según indica el [estándar de C++](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n4296.pdf) (traducción y resaltado míos):

> #### 5.4 Expresiones
>
> **Si durante la evaluación de una expresión, el resultado no está matemáticamente definido** o no está en el rango representable por los valores de su tipo, **el comportamiento es indefinido**. [*Nota:* Muchas de las implementaciones existentes de C++ ignoran el desbordamiento de enteros. **El tratamiento de la división entre cero**, calcular el residuo sobre un divisor cero y todas las excepciones de coma flotante **varían entre máquinas**, y habitualmente es ajustable mediante una función de librería —*fin de la nota* ]

La [división entre cero](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divisi%C3%B3n_por_cero) es, por definición, una indeterminación matemática y (como se recoge en el estándar) provoca comportamiento indefinido y no lanza ninguna excepción; así que no podrás atraparla.

Lo que sí puedes hacer es lanzar la excepción por tu cuenta y atraparla:

```
template <typename DIVIDENDO, typename DIVISOR>
auto divide(DIVIDENDO a, DIVISOR b)
{
    return b == 0 ? throw std::logic_error("divide by zero") : a / b;
}

int main()
{
    try
    {
        std::cout << divide(1, 0) << '\n';
    }
    catch (const std::logic_error &le)
    {
        // hacer cosas
    }
    return 0;
}
```